# Send text to application from TextBox in Android using JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, android, async-await, mocha.js

I am trying to send a string to the app and I have to use the Enter Key in the keyboard to do that. 
I am using Mocha framework.
**So far I tried the below:**

1. await (await this.editText).addValue(message).KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER;
2. await (await this.editText).addValue(message);
   await keyEvent('.my-input', 'keyup', 13);
3. await (await this.editText).addValue(message).KeyboardEvent("key", "66");

But none seems to work. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

After the expected text input action added this:

**await driver.longPressKeyCode(66, undefined, undefined);**